# CSS file ignored when loaded with include in PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I am writing my own MVC implementation and I am facing a problem including local CSS files. Basically all requests in my applications are going to a method which is decomposing them in order to get a controller and action. For example:

`localhost:8888/items/list`
this request will be redirected to my index.php where I have:

`Application::start($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);`

Then the request is decomposed to get the controller 'items' and action 'list' 
So far all good and I didn't realise the problem as I was using bootstrap from CDN. However now if I include in my html something like:

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
```

This will go to my method again and it will not work. 
What I tried is to check if the URI contains 'css' and if it does just include the file with:

```
if(preg_match('/css/',$uri)){
include "../webroot/$uri";}
```

This worked in terms of loading the css but the css is ignored. Also I get

"Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8888/css/style.css"."

The problem is even bigger if I try to include images although with images at least I am able to display them but again through 'include'. Any ideas how to fix this ?

P.S I know that the problem is most likely because the css is loaded as text file, however I don't know how to get this working with my current setup

Comment: Did you try localhost:8080/project_name/css/style.css ?

Comment: There is no problem with loading the css itself, the problem is it is ignored completely for some reason.

Comment: Sure, most likely your script sends the wrong header. To php this is only text. You need to send specific headers indicating that the response actually _is_ css rules.

Comment: Instead of `include()`ing the stylesheet you might want to edit the .htaccess  file (apache) to allow direct access to the style? Or images? Or configure the server in general

Comment: Including the header fixed the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");` with `file_get_contents` instead of include like this

```
if(preg_match('/css/',$uri)){
  header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
  if(!$file = file_get_contents("http://localhost:8080/project_name/webroot/$uri")) return 0;
  echo $file;
}
```